# CodedUI - move code to uimap.cs

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am recording coded ui tests.
After recording- I moved methods to uimap.cs through the uimap.uitest interface, so it will not run over my changes.
All was OK.
On another day, I've added recordings.  Again- I moved methods to uimap.cs through the uimap.uitest interface.
However, this time- when doing so- I get lots of errors of duplicate names - Ambiguity between..., UImap already contains a definition for... and so on.

What are the steps I should do to avoid or fix this?

Thanks :-)

Updating more info I found:
 1.  record and save METHOD1.
 2.  move method1 to UIMAP (all is OK.  Method1 and METHOD1PARAMS moved to uimap and no longer exist in UIMAP.designers.  Only the controls are there).
 3.  record and save METHOD2.
 4. Move METHOD2 to UIMAP.
This is where I get the errors.
What happens is, that now I have METHOD2 and METHOD2PARAMS in both files- UIMAP and UIMAP.DESIGNERS.
I will attach this project shortly.
Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? Like, look through the code to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Hi, thanks.
Yes, the problem is that when moving to uimap- it moves all the GUI elements automatically, but they are already there.
I have around 100 errors about methods' classes and parameters.
I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong with the right click --> move to uimap...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to move the code for UI elements into `UIMap.cs`. It is autogenerated into `UIMap.Designer.cs` from `UIMap.uitest` each time you save the latter.

You can move the code for your test methods into `UIMap.cs` if you wish to edit them beyond what CodedUI test builder and editor allow. The "move code" context menu item in the Coded UI test editor does this.

Make sure to save `UIMap.uitest` after the move so `UIMap.Designer.cs` gets regenerated to reflect the changes.

Comment: That's exactly what I did- I right clicked the method --> and selected move code to uimap.cs.
That's it.
After First recording was fine.  Second time- I got all the errors.

Comment: Did you by any chance name your new recording the same way as an old one? If not, please add info (preferrably, as an example) on where your conflicting methods are located and which is which.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks.
I started over.  Here is step by step what I did:

Comment: Hi,  Thanks.
I started over.  Here is step by step what I did:
1.  Recorded a few steps.  2.  saved it as a method (changed its name).  3.  added asserts (renamed each control).  4.  Saved as a method (changed its name).  Did this twice.  5.  went back to UIMap.uitest.  Right clicked one method --> move code to UIMAP.cs.  All was OK.  6.  went back to UIMap.uitest.  Right clicked another method --> move code to UIMAP.cs.  This time I got errors:  "Ambiguity between '...uimap....' and '...uimap...;  Is there a way to attach here the project?

Comment: This still doesn't let me understand "where your conflicting methods are and which is which". Please update the question with this,including method names and the precise error text.

Comment: For now, I suspect you didn't save the `.uitest` in the Code UI Test Editor after making changes, so `UIMap.Designer.cs` wasn't regenerated to reflect the move.

Comment: I added more details in orig question.  But Do you mean I need to save before continuing?
I'll try it first.

Comment: ivan_pozdeev - Thank you very much!!!
Apperantly, building before saving makes a big mess.
Such a simple solution...
Thanks again :-)

Comment: If the problem is resolved, you might wish to accept the answer. I'll reflect the findings in it now.